# contour is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, image, contour

The error is below:
error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'contourArea'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - contour is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'contour'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def load_image(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    return image

image_path = "/Users/yusufyildirim/Desktop/IMG_7020.jpg"
image = load_image(image_path)

def preprocess_image(image, blur_radius=5):
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (blur_radius, blur_radius), 0)
    _, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(blurred_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return thresholded_image

def find_contours(thresholded_image):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    return list(contours), hierarchy

def calculate_floral_area(contours):
    total_area = 0
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        total_area += area
    return total_area

def find_ruler_contour(contours, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area):
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if min_ruler_area <= area <= max_ruler_area:
            return contour
    return None

def calculate_conversion_factor(ruler_contour, ruler_length_mm):
    ruler_area_pixels = cv2.contourArea(ruler_contour)
    ruler_length_pixels = np.sqrt(ruler_area_pixels)
    conversion_factor = ruler_length_mm / ruler_length_pixels
    return conversion_factor ** 2

def main(image_path, ruler_length_mm, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area):
    image = load_image(image_path)
    thresholded_image = preprocess_image(image)
    contours = find_contours(thresholded_image)
    
    ruler_contour = find_ruler_contour(contours, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area)
    if ruler_contour is None:
        print("Ruler not found")
        return

    conversion_factor = calculate_conversion_factor(ruler_contour, ruler_length_mm)
    contours = [c for c in contours if not np.array_equal(c, ruler_contour)]

    
    floral_area_pixels = calculate_floral_area(contours)
    floral_area_mm2 = floral_area_pixels * conversion_factor

    print(f"Floral area: {floral_area_mm2} square millimeters")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_path = "/Users/yusufyildirim/Desktop/IMG_7020.jpg"
    ruler_length_mm = 1812790
    min_ruler_area = 160000
    max_ruler_area = 200000
    main(image_path, ruler_length_mm, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area)
```

what am I doing wrong here? I'd appreciate help! I don't understand the error for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `find_contours(thresholded_image)` method returns a **tuple**: `list(contours), hierarchy`.

In `find_contours` method, replace: `return list(contours), hierarchy` with:

```
return contours
```

---

When returning the tuple `(list(contours), hierarchy)`:

- The tuple is passed as an argument to `find_ruler_contour`
- The following for loop iterates the tuple (instead of iterating the list of contours):

  ```
   for contour in contours:
       area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
  ```
- In the above code `contour` is actually a tuple: `(list(contours), hierarchy)`
- The first iteration "contour" equals `list(contours)`, and `cv2.contourArea(contour)` fails because `contour` argument is not a contour.
  (in the first iteration, when executing `cv2.contourArea(contour)`, the `contour` argument is actually a list of contours).

---

Since you didn't post the input image, I created a synthetic image for reproducing the issue:

```
def load_image(image_path):
    #image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    # Build synthetic image for testing
    ############################################################################
    image = np.full((600, 1000, 3), 255, np.uint8)
    image[50:250, 50:950, :] = 0
    image[300:550, 50:950, :] = 0
    ############################################################################
    return image
```

Note: I don't know what you are measuring, and it's not important in the context of the question (the synthetic image reproduces the error)...

---

Corrected code sample (with synthetic image for testing):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def load_image(image_path):
    #image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    # Build synthetic image for testing
    ############################################################################
    image = np.full((600, 1000, 3), 255, np.uint8)
    image[50:250, 50:950, :] = 0
    image[300:550, 50:950, :] = 0
    ############################################################################
    return image

image_path = "/Users/yusufyildirim/Desktop/IMG_7020.jpg"
image = load_image(image_path)

def preprocess_image(image, blur_radius=5):
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (blur_radius, blur_radius), 0)
    _, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(blurred_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return thresholded_image

def find_contours(thresholded_image):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #return list(contours), hierarchy
    return contours  # We may also return list(contours), but we don't have to.

def calculate_floral_area(contours):
    total_area = 0
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        total_area += area
    return total_area

def find_ruler_contour(contours, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area):
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if min_ruler_area <= area <= max_ruler_area:
            return contour
    return None

def calculate_conversion_factor(ruler_contour, ruler_length_mm):
    ruler_area_pixels = cv2.contourArea(ruler_contour)
    ruler_length_pixels = np.sqrt(ruler_area_pixels)
    conversion_factor = ruler_length_mm / ruler_length_pixels
    return conversion_factor ** 2

def main(image_path, ruler_length_mm, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area):
    image = load_image(image_path)
    thresholded_image = preprocess_image(image)
    contours = find_contours(thresholded_image)
    
    ruler_contour = find_ruler_contour(contours, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area)
    if ruler_contour is None:
        print("Ruler not found")
        return

    conversion_factor = calculate_conversion_factor(ruler_contour, ruler_length_mm)
    contours = [c for c in contours if not np.array_equal(c, ruler_contour)]

    
    floral_area_pixels = calculate_floral_area(contours)
    floral_area_mm2 = floral_area_pixels * conversion_factor

    print(f"Floral area: {floral_area_mm2} square millimeters")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_path = "/Users/yusufyildirim/Desktop/IMG_7020.jpg"
    ruler_length_mm = 1812790
    min_ruler_area = 160000
    max_ruler_area = 200000
    main(image_path, ruler_length_mm, min_ruler_area, max_ruler_area)
```